# Change the notification sound in the new Inbox by Gmail

Tags: notifications, inbox-by-gmail

I looked for a way to change the default notification sound for new e-mails in Inbox but could not find the setting. In the Gmail app I could change the sound.

Does anyone know how to change it or if this is just using the default system sound?

I'm using a Nexus 4.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is possible now. From the [Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067586?hl=en#android_settings):

1. Open the Inbox app.
2. Go to the main menu at the top left.
3. Scroll down and choose Settings near the bottom.
4. Select your email address.
5. Make sure Notifications is checked.
6. Click 'inbox sound and vibrate'.
7. Click on "Sound" and choose your preferred notification tone.

Answer (score 3):

With Gmail version 2019.03.03.240577312.release on an Android 8 phone:

1. Open Gmail, then settings.
2. Select the account you want to modify.
3. Select Manage notifications.
4. Select Sound, then choose a new sound among the list. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google did not include a way to change the notification sound in the Inbox app.

It does use the default system notification sound.

The only workaround as I see it is to change the default system sound to the one you want to use for Inbox, and then change all other app notification sounds as needed.

I use different sounds for each app that gives me notifications anyway, so for me changing the system default effectively only changed the Inbox sound.

Answer (score 0):

Use the app [NotifiCon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=notificon.gsy.com.notificon). With this app you can change the new Gmail notification.